# What does Entitlements.entitlements do?

Tags: ios

In one of projects , there is a file called Entitlements.entitlements, what does this file do?

The content inside is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

> "Entitlements confer specific capabilities or security permissions to your iOS or OS X app.
>
> Set entitlement values in order to enable iCloud, push notifications, and App Sandbox. Each entitlement has a default value, which in most cases disables the capability associated with the entitlement. When you set an entitlement, you are overriding the default by providing an appropriate key-value pair.
>
> - iCloud entitlements let you enable the use of iCloud data storage for
>     your iOS or OS X app.
> - You set iCloud entitlement values on a target-by-target basis in your
>     Xcode project.
> - Push notifications let your app alert the user even when your iOS or
>     OS X app is not executing.
> - You set push notification entitlement values as part of configuring
>     your development and distribution provisioning profiles.
> - App Sandbox entitlements let you enable the security feature called
>     sandboxing for your OS X app. (In iOS, all apps are sandboxed
>     automatically, so these sandboxing entitlements do not apply.)
> - By carefully enabling only the resource access that you need, you
>     minimize the potential for damage if malicious code successfully
>     exploits your app. You set App Sandbox entitlement values on a
>     target-by-target basis in your Xcode project."

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html

**EDIT**

Currently, it looks like this Entitlements plist that you have is empty.

To explain what the parts of it are, the:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

Is a Document Type Definition (DTD), and is a markup declaration to define the document type for this XML file.

The:

```
<plist version="1.0">
```

Just tells you the version type of the plist.

And the:

```
<key>get-task-allow</key>
```

"When signed into an application, allows other processes (like the debugger) to attach to your app. Distribution profiles require that this value be turned off, while development profiles require this value to be turned on (otherwise Xcode would never be able to launch and attach to your app)" [(taken from this link)](https://devforums.apple.com/message/84647#84647). It takes a `BOOL` value, which looks like it is currenly set to `<false/>`

I hope that answers your question and covers everything.